# Failure to install mysql on macOS Mojave

Tags: mojave, homebrew, mysql

I've moved to a new machine and installing MySQL is turning out to be quite an issue (the last time I installed it on a mac it was quite seamless).

I used two approaches to install MySQL: `brew` and the `offical installer`

**Brew**:

I started with `brew install mysql`. This installed the latest version of MySQL. It initially worked and I could log into the root user *without* a password. When I tried to set the password for the root account I ended up being locked out of the root account. I proceeded to uninstall that version of MySQL and tried a different version (5.7). When I installed that I got the following error: `ERROR 2061 (HY000): Authentication plugin 'sha256_password' reported error: Authentication requires SSL encryption`. I ended up uninstalling that version of MySQL as well.

**Native Package**:

Tried the latest version was asked for a password but could not login to the root user with the password. Received this error: `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock'`. Additionally I could not run `mysql.server start`, received the following error: `command not found: mysql.server`. I did not add anything to my PATH, should I have done that?

Additionally, this is how the MySQL widget in the System Information looks like. I tried pressing `Start MySQL Server` a bunch of times, it would start and almost immediately stop.

Can anyone suggest a clean way in which I can remove all these defunct installations and have a clean MySQL install?

[image: MySQL server not starting]

Answer (score 1):

MySQL 8 makes big changes compared with previous version 5.7. Downgrading directly to the lower version 5.7 from 8.x won't work.

Solution:

1. Uninstall all MySQLs you've installed.
2. Since you're setting up a new machine, there's no existing database. Just clean up the broken database.

   ```sh
   # brew-installed mysql
   rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql

   # db from the official installed
   # should be located at /usr/local/mysql (I'm not very sure)
   ls -ald /usr/local/*mysql*
   # then delete any folders listed by ls
   ```
3. You'd better remove the conf file `/usr/local/etc/my.cnf` as well.
4. Reinstall MySQL.